# Group pandas dataframe by a nested dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns is dictionary type. This is an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 
                   'b': [4,5,6], 
                   'version': [{'major': 7, 'minor':1}, 
                               {'major':8, 'minor': 5},
                               {'major':7, 'minor':2}] })
```

df:

```
   a  b                   version
0  1  4  {'minor': 1, 'major': 7}
1  2  5  {'minor': 5, 'major': 8}
2  3  6  {'minor': 2, 'major': 7}
```

I am looking for a way to group the dataframe by one of that dictionary key; in this case to group the **df** dataframe by the **major** key in **version** label.

I have tried a few different stuff, from passing the dictionary key to dataframe groupby function, `df.groupby(['version']['major']), which doesn't work since **major** is not part of dataframe label, to assigning **version** to the dataframe index, but nothing works so far. I'm also trying to flatten the dictionaries as additional columns in the dataframe itself, but this seems to have its own issue.

Any idea?

P.S. Sorry about formatting, it's my first stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Option 1***

```
df.groupby(df.version.apply(lambda x: x['major'])).size()

version
7    2
8    1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
df.groupby(df.version.apply(lambda x: x['major']))[['a', 'b']].sum()
```

[image]

***Option 2***

```
df.groupby(df.version.apply(pd.Series).major).size()

major
7    2
8    1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
df.groupby(df.version.apply(pd.Series).major)[['a', 'b']].sum()
```

[image]

Comment: i like your version

Comment: Excellent! I didn't think `apply` function works as index selector to the dataframe. Thanks, @piRSquared!

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
In [15]: df.assign(major=df.version.apply(pd.Series).major).groupby('major').sum()
Out[15]:
       a   b
major
7      4  10
8      2   5
```

Comment: I've never seen `assign` before.  I've learned something new today.

Comment: Yeah, `assign` would have saved me so many `concat` and `merge`.