# Group by using multiple occurrences of a nested key in a single record

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   a  b                   version
0  1  4  [{'x': 'q', 'y': 7},{'x': 's', 'y': 7}]
1  2  5  [{'x': 'r', 'y': 8},{'x': 'q','y': 8}]
2  3  6  [{'x': 's', 'y': 7}]
```

I want to group_by x.

I tried out the solution in here but I'm getting a keyerror likey because of multiple dicts in version.

[Group pandas dataframe by a nested dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881679/group-pandas-dataframe-by-a-nested-dictionary-key)

This is what I tried:

```
df.groupby(df.version.apply(lambda x: x['x'])).size()
```

Expected result:

```
q 2
s 2
r 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a simple `sum` on `df.version` and construct dataframe from the result and `value_counts` on column `x`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.version.sum()).x.value_counts()

Out[577]:
q    2
s    2
r    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you apparently don't use column `a` and `b`, just chain your dicts and get a brand new data frame to work with

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.version))
ndf.groupby('x').size()
```

---

```
x
q    2
r    1
s    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case you do need to use `a` and `b` you can unfold the `version` column into rows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 4, [{'x': 'q', 'y': 7},{'x': 's', 'y': 7}]],
        [2, 5, [{'x': 'r', 'y': 8},{'x': 'q','y': 8}]],
        [3, 6,  [{'x': 's', 'y': 7}]]
    ], columns = ['a','b', 'version']
)

## count elements inside "version"
df['elements'] = df['version'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

## flatten x into a list of dictionaries
values = df['version'].values.flatten().tolist()
flat_results = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]

## reinsert a and b
new_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_results)
new_df['a'] = df['a'].repeat(df['elements'].values).values
new_df['b'] = df['b'].repeat(df['elements'].values).values

new_df
Out[42]: 
   x  y  a  b
0  q  7  1  4
1  s  7  1  4
2  r  8  2  5
3  q  8  2  5
4  s  7  3  6


## group by x
new_df.groupby('x').agg({'a': 'count', 'b': 'count', 'y': 'count'})

Out[41]: 
   a  b  y
x         
q  2  2  2
r  1  1  1
s  2  2  2
```