# Grouping a dict by a dynamic key name and aggregating some of the keys of a nested dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping, aggregation

I am struggling with grouping a nested dict by a key (in the nested dict) and by aggregating some of the nested dict's data.
I hope that someone here can give me some helpful hints since I am not making any progress. I am using Python 3.6 and I looked at the collections and pandas module, figuring that the pandas module might contain the stuff I need to reach my goal.

The following dict is provided:

```
{
  12345: {
    'date': '2019-07-26',
    'time_spent': 0.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 1804
  },
  54321: {
    'date': '2019-07-26',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  11561: {
    'date': '2019-07-25',
    'time_spent': 1.25,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 1449
  },
  12101: {
    'date': '2019-07-25',
    'time_spent': 0.25,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 2607
  },
  12337: {
    'date': '2019-07-24',
    'time_spent': 2.0,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  54123: {
    'date': '2019-07-24',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 4831
  },
  15931: {
    'date': '2019-07-19',
    'time_spent': 3.0,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  13412: {
    'date': '2019-07-19',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 1449
  }
}
```

Consider it as a list of test drives a car seller had during these days, with time spent on a single test drive and having the sales opportunity evaluated by colors. Now, I need to group this data:

- Group it by date, so a new dict may contain the single dates as keys
- Aggregate the time_spent on a single date and provide a sum for this date
- Bring the colors with me, but if the colors mix up for one day (e.g. having red and yellow), red always wins
- For each date, have an aggregated list of drive_id, comma separated
- Throw away the key names of the top level dict

So it might just look like this when I transform the data manually:

```
{
  '2019-07-26':
  {
    'time_spent': '2.0',
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': '1804, 3105',

  },
  '2019-07-25':
  {
    'time_spent': '1.5',
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': '1449, 2607',

  },
  '2019-07-24':
  {
    'time_spent': '3.5',
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': '3105, 4831',

  },
  '2019-07-19':
  {
    'time_spent': '4.5',
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': '1449, 3105',
  }

}
```

Now where is my obstacle? Clearly, I have limited Python skills and I struggle with the dict key name (e.g. 13412) being generated dynamically. I found this solution here ([Group pandas dataframe by a nested dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881679/group-pandas-dataframe-by-a-nested-dictionary-key/38881727#comment101189029_38881727)) but I can't apply this solution to my case since the dict key name is not known here in advance. So I basically tried to create a pandas DataFrame and group the original dict by date first, but I already fail there.

I apologize if I might have overlooked something in the pandas docs or a question here at StackOverflow. I would highly appreciate it if someone could give me a hint and explain to me how to approach such a case.

Comment: There're two objects with `'date': '2019-07-24'`, what to do in that case?

Comment: @OlvinRoght: The middle bullets all address this.

Comment: Have you solved *any* part or version of this?  If so, please post it; if not, start by trying to.

Comment: You might want to investigate the `dict` method `items`.

Comment: At first, I tried grouping the stuff by date without data aggregation. However, when I try this, it gives me an error message about my key ("date"). I can try it again and post the code + the explicit error message if this helps.

Comment: @Valentin Edit your question and show all the code you have so far, plus any error messages.

Comment: I've got an answer that gets it into a nice dataframe, perfect for additional analysis! including groupby's

Answer (score 1):

With simple iteration and using `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {
  12345: {
    'date': '2019-07-26',
    'time_spent': 0.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 1804
  },
  54321: {
    'date': '2019-07-26',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  11561: {
    'date': '2019-07-25',
    'time_spent': 1.25,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 1449
  },
  12101: {
    'date': '2019-07-25',
    'time_spent': 0.25,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 2607
  },
  12337: {
    'date': '2019-07-24',
    'time_spent': 2.0,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  54123: {
    'date': '2019-07-24',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 4831
  },
  15931: {
    'date': '2019-07-19',
    'time_spent': 3.0,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  13412: {
    'date': '2019-07-19',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 1449
  }
}

out = {}
for item in d.values():
    out.setdefault(item['date'], {})
    out[item['date']].setdefault('time_spent', 0.0)
    out[item['date']].setdefault('color', 'yellow')
    out[item['date']].setdefault('drive_id', [])

    out[item['date']]['time_spent'] += item['time_spent']
    if item['color'] == 'red':
        out[item['date']]['color'] = 'red'
    out[item['date']]['drive_id'].append(item['drive_id'])

#post-processing
for k in out.values():
    k['drive_id'] = ', '.join(str(i) for i in k['drive_id'])
    k['time_spent'] = str(k['time_spent'])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'2019-07-19': {'color': 'red', 'drive_id': '3105, 1449', 'time_spent': '4.5'},
 '2019-07-24': {'color': 'yellow',
                'drive_id': '3105, 4831',
                'time_spent': '3.5'},
 '2019-07-25': {'color': 'red', 'drive_id': '1449, 2607', 'time_spent': '1.5'},
 '2019-07-26': {'color': 'yellow',
                'drive_id': '1804, 3105',
                'time_spent': '2.0'}}
```

Comment: Thank you. So you say no special things like pandas are needed? That actually already helps me a lot. Will try to have a look at dict.setdefault. Edit: I saw you also posted the code. Also thank you for this. Will try to reverse engineer and understand your sample.

Comment: @Valentin no special modules needed in this simple case. I would keep however  `drive_id` as `list` and `time_spent` as `float` for better manipulation afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect anyone to give me a working solution, just some hints on how to make some progress. But I will study your code and consider your hints regarding keeping it as float and using lists for the drive_id.

Comment: Oh my.. this is too simple to be true. I tried it a similar way, but a) I did not know that "setdefault" would make sense here and b) I had various key errors with "date", maybe because of the type of "date". Anyway, this solution is simple and requires only basic Python understanding. Thanks again for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do any library checking, but I created the following script to complete your task. The pre-defined variable in this script is `data`, which is your `dict`. This is edited in the script.

The script is below:

```
for i in data.values():

    # Get the date, which will be the key for the replacement entry
    date = data[i]['date']

    # Splits the track. Is this date already defined in the dict?
    try:

        # This is the line that does it. If this line succeeds, there is aleady
        # a key in this dict for this date. We must do some appending things.
        data[date]

        # Color: red wins if it comes between red or yellow.
        data[date]['color'] = 'red' if data[date]['color'] == 'red' or \
                data[i]['color'] == 'red' else 'yellow'

        # Time spent: sum of the two
        data[date]['time_spent'] = data[date]['time_spent'] + \
                data[i]['time_spent']

        # Drive ID: append
        data[date]['drive_id'] = str(data[date]['drive_id']) + ', ' + \
                str(data[i]['drive_id'])

    # If the date fails to get, we catch the error and add a new date entry.
    except KeyError:

        # Adds the new date entry
        data.update({date: data[i]})

        # Removes the duplicate date entry
        data[date].pop('date')

    # Removes the old entry
    data.pop(i)
```

Running this, assuming `date` and `date_old` are defined converts `data` to the following dict:

```
{'2019-07-26': {'time_spent': 2.0, 'color': 'yellow', 'drive_id': '1804, 3105'}, '2019-07-25': {'time_spent': 1.5, 'color': 'red', 'drive_id': '1449, 2607'}, '2019-07-24': {'time_spent': 3.5, 'color': 'yellow', 'drive_id': '3105, 4831'}, '2019-07-19': {'time_spent': 4.5, 'color': 'red', 'drive_id': '3105, 1449'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
input = {
    12345: {
        'date': '2019-07-26',
        'time_spent': 0.5,
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': 1804
    },
    54321: {
        'date': '2019-07-26',
        'time_spent': 1.5,
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': 3105
    },
    11561: {
        'date': '2019-07-25',
        'time_spent': 1.25,
        'color': 'red',
        'drive_id': 1449
    },
    12101: {
        'date': '2019-07-25',
        'time_spent': 0.25,
        'color': 'red',
        'drive_id': 2607
    },
    12337: {
        'date': '2019-07-24',
        'time_spent': 2.0,
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': 3105
    },
    54123: {
        'date': '2019-07-24',
        'time_spent': 1.5,
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': 4831
    },
    15931: {
        'date': '2019-07-19',
        'time_spent': 3.0,
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': 3105
    },
    13412: {
        'date': '2019-07-19',
        'time_spent': 1.5,
        'color': 'red',
        'drive_id': 1449
    }
}

output = {}
for value in input.values():
    obj = output.get(value['date'], None)
    if not obj:
        obj = {
            'time_spent': str(value['time_spent']),
            'color': value['color'],
            'drive_id': str(value['drive_id'])
        }
        output[value['date']] = obj
    else:
        obj['time_spent'] = str(float(obj['time_spent']) + value['time_spent'])
        if value['color'] == 'red':
            obj['color'] = value['color']
        obj['drive_id'] += ', ' + str(value['drive_id'])
```

Output:

```
{
    '2019-07-26': {
        'time_spent': '2.0',
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': '1804, 3105'
    },
    '2019-07-25': {
        'time_spent': '1.5',
        'color': 'red',
        'drive_id': '1449, 2607'
    },
    '2019-07-24': {
        'time_spent': '3.5',
        'color': 'yellow',
        'drive_id': '3105, 4831'
    },
    '2019-07-19': {
        'time_spent': '4.5',
        'color': 'red',
        'drive_id': '3105, 1449'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect that anyone would post code which is ready to use, I would have already been very happy with a hint where to look next. However, I appreciate your efforts and will try to understand your code.

Comment: @Valentin, it seems pretty obvious, but if you have any questions - feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go! pandas will make all your aggregation much easier!

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
  12345: {
    'date': '2019-07-26',
    'time_spent': 0.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 1804
  },
  54321: {
    'date': '2019-07-26',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  11561: {
    'date': '2019-07-25',
    'time_spent': 1.25,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 1449
  },
  12101: {
    'date': '2019-07-25',
    'time_spent': 0.25,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 2607
  },
  12337: {
    'date': '2019-07-24',
    'time_spent': 2.0,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  54123: {
    'date': '2019-07-24',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 4831
  },
  15931: {
    'date': '2019-07-19',
    'time_spent': 3.0,
    'color': 'yellow',
    'drive_id': 3105
  },
  13412: {
    'date': '2019-07-19',
    'time_spent': 1.5,
    'color': 'red',
    'drive_id': 1449
  }
}

dd = {str(k): v for k, v in d.items()}

pd.read_json(json.dumps(dd), orient='records').transpose()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['drive_id'] = df['drive_id'].astype(str)
df = df.reset_index()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    index   color   date    drive_id    time_spent
0   12345   yellow  2019-07-26  1804    0.5
1   54321   yellow  2019-07-26  3105    1.5
2   11561   red 2019-07-25  1449    1.25
3   12101   red 2019-07-25  2607    0.25
4   12337   yellow  2019-07-24  3105    2
5   54123   yellow  2019-07-24  4831    1.5
6   15931   yellow  2019-07-19  3105    3
7   13412   red 2019-07-19  1449    1.5
```

**GROUPBY DATE AND GET ID LIST**

```
df.pivot_table(index=['date'], values=['drive_id'], aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()

    date    drive_id
0   2019-07-19  3105,1449
1   2019-07-24  3105,4831
2   2019-07-25  1449,2607
3   2019-07-26  1804,3105
```